# How to serialize Name/Value pairs as Attributes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

```
public class MyStuff {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Annotation> Annotations { get; set; }
}

public class Annotation {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the List of Annotations to serialize as a bunch of XML attributes?

```
var x = new MyStuff {
    Name = "Stuff",
    Annotations = new [] {
        new Annotation { Name = "Note1", Value = "blah" },
        new Annotation { Name = "Note2", Value = "blahblah" }
    }.ToList()
};

// turns into something like:
<MyStuff Name="Stuff" ann:Note1="blah" ann:Note2="blahblah" />
```

Comment: Please give us some information about what your xml should look like after serialization

Comment: Very last line on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface allows you to customize the serialization of any class.

```
public class MyStuff : IXmlSerializable {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Annotation> Annotations { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        // customized deserialization
        // reader.GetAttribute() or whatever
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        // customized serialization
        // writer.WriteAttributeString() or whatever
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ann:Note1` is only valid if `ann` is an xml namespace,

```
XNamespace ns = "Annotation";

XElement xElem = new XElement("MyStuff", new XAttribute("Name",x.Name));
xElem.Add(x.Annotations
           .Select(a => new XAttribute(ns + a.Name, a.Value)));

var xml = xElem.ToString();
```

OUTPUT:

```
<MyStuff Name="Stuff" p1:Note1="blah" p1:Note2="blahblah" xmlns:p1="Annotation" />
```

Comment: That's the correct output that I want, but I want to use Serialization.  This is part of a large object hierarchy, and I'd prefer not to re-write the entire thing.

Comment: @harley.333 It would be too tricky, if possible, with xml serialization. You may first need to transform your object to a different one and then do the serialization(it wouldn't much different than above code then)

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); // Creating an xml document
XmlElement root =doc.CreateElement("rootelement"); doc.AppendChild(root); // Creating and appending the root element
XmlElement annotation = doc.CreateElement("Name");
XmlElement value = doc.CreateElement("Value");
annotation.InnerText = "Annotation Name Here";
value.InnerText = "Value Here";
doc.AppendChild(annotation);
doc.AppendChild(value);
```

You can narrow all your list and do the same thing in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add the attribute `[XmlAttribute]` on your properties:

```
public class Annotation
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the result will be like this:

```
<Annotations>
  <Annotation Name="Note1" Value="blah" /> 
  <Annotation Name="Note2" Value="blahblah" /> 
</Annotations>
```